# Restrict access to one Elastic Beanstalk app from another

Tags: security, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have two Elastic Beanstalk applications "a" and "b".  Anyone should be able to talk to (a) over http, but only (a) should be able to talk to (b).  I.e.

```
internet -> a -> b
```

Right now, everything works if both apps are fully open to the internet.  But as soon as I try to restrict the security group for (b)'s ELB, (a) can't seem to connect anymore.

I.e. If I allow (b)'s load balancer security group to allow http:0.0.0.0/0, everything works.  But if I set that same security group to allow only http:[(a)'s security group], (a) can no longer communicate with (b).

Both apps are in the same VPC.  What am I missing?

-- Edit --

To be explicit:

- App B:

  - ELB Security Group: sg-a3d3ccc6
  - EC2 Security Group: sg-aed3cccb
- App A:

  - ELB Security Group: sg-4fe5fd2a
  - EC2 Security Group: sg-5ee5fd3b

Working:

App A's ELB Security Group Settings, to allow access from anyone to HTTP/S
[image: App A's ELB Security Group Settings, to allow access from anyone to HTTP/S]

App A's EC2 Security Group, to allow access only from A's ELB (yes, I'm missing https here, but that's OK for now)
[image: App A's EC2 Security Group, to allow access only from A's ELB]

App B's ELB Security Group, to allow access from anyone
[image: App B's ELB Security Group, to allow access from anyone]

App B's EC2 Security Group, to allow access only from B's ELB
[image: App B's EC2 Security Group, to allow access only from B's ELB]

NOT Working:

Everything same as above, but change B's ELB Security Group to only allow access from A's EC2 group.  Heck, just to be sure, we'll add A's EC2 AND ELB.

App B's ELB Security Group, allowing access only from App A
[image: App B's ELB Security Group, allowing access only from App A]

Comment: Additionally - if I specify the IP address of (a), everything works.  But that's not helpful in an Elastic Beanstalk setup where the instances will be torn down and relaunched at will.  Why doesn't the security group as a source work...?

Comment: Can you show exactly what you tried maybe in screenshots? What you're describing should work, maybe there's a typo?

Comment: Check if you are actually adding A's security group or A's ELB's security group. I suspect you are adding A'S ELB's security group (B's ELB) which would be wrong as ELB is not communicating with B but the instances are. Also, B (instances) only needs incoming from B's ELB

Comment: Sadly, no.  I made sure I was adding A's security group, not its ELB.  Though just to make sure I did add both, but neither worked.  I'll update my question to include some specifics...

Comment: Does your app A servers have elastic IPs by any chance? If so, they won't be identifying themselves by their SG but by IP address.

Comment: No Elastic IPs at all.  There is the ELB, and a Route 53 entry pointing to those, but no Elastic IPs.

Comment: I can't figure out what is going wrong here. My last bet would be to check the App B's logs when it is open to world and look for the incoming requests. Is it coming from the App A's instances or somewhere else. I have this exact setup for one of my stacks and it is working for me.

Answer (score 3):

If anyone has this working (as some have claimed), I'd be very interested in details.  I signed up for a support account and opened a ticket with AWS, and officially they say this isn't possible:

> After researching this more the setup that you are trying to implement
>   isn't supported. In the section of the security group rules it states
>   that when referencing a security group in a SG rule it allows access
>   from the local IP addresses of instances associated with the source
>   group, not their public or Elastic IP. Below is the documentation page
>   with more information on the topic.
>
> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html#security-group-rules
>
> To accomplish what you want to do will require a bit more setup, but
>   is possible.
>
> Below I've included a link to a tutorial that lays out the process of
>   deploying an EB environment into a VPC with instances in a private
>   subnet as well as the process of setting up a NAT instance on AWS.
>   Using this it will allow you to have your private EB applications
>   instances accessible from only the public EB application.
>
> I would recommend setting up a new VPC with this architecture in mind
>   rather than try to modify your existing VPC.
>
> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/AWSHowTo-vpc-basic.html
>   http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_NAT_Instance.html#NATInstance

I.e. the traffic between the two EB instances is from A's public IP address, but security groups only work against private IP addresses.  I haven't finished reading yet, but it looks like the solution is to create a new VPC and NAT the two together, so all requests look like they're coming from the private IP addresses.

That's kind of gross, not the least of which is that creating all new VPCs would be a royal pain.  So very curious if others out there have this working without that.

Comment: Hi, I m facing the same issue, so wondering whether you ve found a decent solution to that